# How to put variables in numerical order

Tags: php

I have some variables which contain numbers. I am trying to return those variables but I want them in numerical order.

For example

```
$result = $random_number_1 . ':' . $random_number_2;
```

How can I make sure the lowest number is always first without knowing what the number is?

So the result can be 1:2 but never 2:1.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to sort numbers? Did you try https://www.php.net/sort?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an array as the container for these numbers (which you can then easily sort the way you want)?

```php
$numbers = []; // <-- fill it up with random numbers using a for cycle or similar
sort($numbers);
$result = implode(':', $numbers) // <-- have them put together as a string, if wanted
```

Comment: `array_sort()`, you mean `sort()`?

Comment: @jibsteroos Yes, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the beautiful ternary operator

```
$result = $random_number_1 < $random_number_2? $random_number_1 . ':' . $random_number_2: $random_number_2 . ':' . $random_number_1;
```